# How to make a swipe navigation drawer with Material

Tags: javascript, css, angular-material

I am making an android app with the Webview technique. To make a look and feel like an android I am using a Material CSS (https://daemonite.github.io/material/) framework.

Now my problem is the drawer is not touch-sensitive. I can't push it back like an android drawer. The drawer can only close by touching outside of this. Please solve the problem.

```html
   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, width=device-width" name="viewport">
  <title>Material</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <!-- Add Material font (Roboto) and Material icon as needed -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Add Material CSS, replace Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="/material/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Additional CSS for documentation site -->
  <link href="/material/docs/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-light h-100">
  <header class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-full bg-primary doc-navbar-default">
    <button aria-controls="navdrawerDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navdrawer" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navdrawerDefault" data-toggle="navdrawer"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <span class="navbar-brand mr-auto">Navdrawer</span>
  </header>

  <div aria-hidden="true" class="navdrawer" id="navdrawerDefault" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="navdrawer-content">
      <div class="navdrawer-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand px-0" href="javascript:void(0)">Navdrawer header</a>
      </div>
      <nav class="navdrawer-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Disabled</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="navdrawer-divider"></div>
      <p class="navdrawer-subheader">Navdrawer subheader</p>
      <ul class="navdrawer-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons mr-3">alarm_on</i> Active with icon</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons mr-3">alarm_off</i> Disabled with icon</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons mr-3">link</i> Link with icon</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Material JavaScript on top of Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="/material/js/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You did not post enought code for us to help you. Please click edit and then edit above snippet (I made for you) and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sir, thanks for your valuable comment. After clicking edit I have paste the full code, but in the snippet, it is not working. I am giving a URL to clarify the design. [link](http://daemonite.github.io/material/docs/4.1/examples/navdrawer-default.html)